# Android service terminates when app terminates

Tags: android, android-service

I am currently trying to implement an app that has a service running until the user explicitly ends it via the app. I would like the service to remain on otherwise. My current problem is that whenever the app is removed from the recent apps, it terminates the service as well. I have tried using START_STICKY in my onStartCommand but it doesn't change anything.

```
public class TriggerService extends Service{

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

and here is my code for when I call the service:

```
public void startServ(boolean state){
    editor = sp.edit();

    if (state == true) {
        startService(new Intent(currentActivity, TriggerService.class));
        editor.putBoolean("service_status", true);
        toast = Toast.makeText(currentActivity, "Service Running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    } else {
        stopService(new Intent(currentActivity, TriggerService.class));
        editor.putBoolean("service_status", false);
        toast = Toast.makeText(currentActivity, "Service Not Running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

    editor.commit();
}
```

EDIT: I added

```
android:isolatedProcess="true"
```

to the androidmanifest for the service as suggested but the service terminates when the app does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. The above code will work. The problem is there is a bug in the code for 4.4.2 which terminates services related to apps when you terminate those apps. An example of the issue is here http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/03/07/bug-watch-stopping-apps-on-android-4-4-2-can-silently-kill-related-background-services-a-fix-is-on-the-way/ with the bug tracker here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63793

Answer (score 3):

When a user swipes an app out of the recent history list, the process is terminated. If you start a service inside the same process as your activity, that service will be terminated when the user swipes the app out.

The guide mentions starting services in different processes by simply setting a flag in the manifest but that will require you to use AIDL to move data between the service and the app or move the data indirectly via intents.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html

```
<service android:enabled=["true" | "false"]
         android:exported=["true" | "false"]
         android:icon="drawable resource"
         android:isolatedProcess=["true" | "false"]
         android:label="string resource"
         android:name="string"
         android:permission="string"
         android:process="string" >
    . . .
</service>
```

Comment: I added android:isolatedProcess="true" to the manifest under the service and unfortunately the service still terminates when the app is removed from recents. Do I need to start the service differently?

Comment: Pretty sure you need to set the process flag and not the isolated process flag. I believe you would so something like android:process="myProcess".

Comment: I tried adding the android:process="testProcess" tag and that created two services running at all time but they still terminated when the app was terminated. I changed the process name to 'com.bionicsheep.lppie.TriggerService" to map it to the service class which reduced it to just one running service when it started but unfortunately it just closed when the app terminated too :/

Comment: Try putting a : in front of the name followed by a lower case letter. That makes the process global and maybe that will resolve it. I actually have this exact same issue at work and I have just been too buried to try out these steps. Really hope that fixes it.

Comment: This is so frustrating, so many apps have constantly running service yet I can't find any examples that truly work. Thanks for trying to help. I tried ":myservice" but same issue. If you ever figure it out at work please report back.